# Resteasy - supporting both JBoss AS 7 and Wildfly

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, resteasy, wildfly

We have to support both JBoss AS 7.1.3 and Wildfly in our project.
To provide this possibility we have two maven profiles with different dependencies and versions, which are provided in AS.
Everything works fine, but recently we faced problem in JBoss, connected with Resteasy.

Our REST services annotated with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

But if we e.g. made `PUT` request with no `Content-Type` header field set, we get response with `404` status.
We expect response with `415 Unsupported Media Type`, so we wrote interceptor to check the `MediaType` and throw `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` if it's not set.

In the Wildfly this problem is fixed, so we don't need this interceptor.

The main problem is that the Resteasy major version is different in Wildfly - 
3.0.8.Final (in JBoss 7.1.3 it was 2.3.3.Final) and there are some incompatible changes.

E.g. our interceptor implements `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PreProcessInterceptor` which is marked as Deprecated in Resteasy 3.0.8 and the signature of it's `preProcess` method has changed since Resteasy 2.3.3.

The signature of `PreProcessInterceptor.preProcess` for 2.3.3:

```
ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException;
```

and for 3.0.8:

```
ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethodInvoker method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException;
```

So our interceptor even won't compile for Wildfly.

The question is: how to resolve this issue to make code compilable for both JBoss AS 7.1.3/Wildfly and avoid using this interceptor in Wildfly?

The interceptor registered via annotations:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class MyInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor
```

P.S. We have interop module to provide classes which are different in these platforms, e.g. have different package names.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading Resteasy is not an option because we don't have direct access to the customer's systems, and out app is not the only one to use Resteasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come up with the following solution:

1. Create my own interface

   `public interface MyPreProcessInterceptor extends PreProcessInterceptor
   {
       //method signature for Restesy 2.3.3
       ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
               throws Failure, WebApplicationException;`

   ```
   //method signature for Restesy 3.0.8
   ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethodInvoker method)
           throws Failure, WebApplicationException;
   ```

   }
2. Create `ResourceMethod` class in the interop for Wildfly
3. Create `ResourceMethodInvoker` class in the interop for JBoss AS 7.1.3
4. Modify `MyInterceptor` to implement new interface `MyPreProcessInterceptor`
5. Implement the necessary logic only in the method for Restesy 2.3.3, and just `return null;` for 3.0.8

So now it compiles and works for both platforms now.